# Unable to install HAXM in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, haxm

I tried installing HAXM with android studio on my laptop. The installation was successful initially but i still fail to run an AVD on my laptop. Can someone clarify on this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check if virtualization is enabled in your bios settings. If it is not enabled tben emulator wont work. Try this and let me know @SaiharshitN

Comment: Thank you @Nomankhanbhai. Working perfectly now.

Comment: You are welcome @N.SaiHarshit I am posting this as a answer kindly mark it as correct. so it can help others

Answer (score 0):

**Check if *virtualization* is enabled in your bios settings. If it is not enabled then emulator won't work. Try this**